# Изменить тип диска с HDD на SSD в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, hyper-v

На гипервизоре Hyper-V настновлена гостевая ОС Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
Я выделил два пространства на двух дисках. Один SSD другой HDD.
Так вот конерь (систему) я установил на SSD.
Но этот диск оределяется как HDD.

```
 cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational
1
```

Как изменить определение диска с HDD на SSD?
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: 1. *Но этот диск оределяется как HDD* — как вы это определили? 2. а что с вашей точки зрения должно измениться?

Comment: Вот так и определил  "cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational" http://wiki.docking.org/index.php/How_to_Check_Harddrive_information

Comment: Все логично, гипервизор презентует виртуальной машине виртуальный жесткий диск. если вы хотите, чтобы "экономился" ресурс SSD разметьте ее в ReFS к примеру. а виртуалка ничего не знает про то на каком физическом носителе ее синтетический диск находится, он может быть перемещен без уведомления вм в любой момент в другое место, например на SMB / CSV том который в свою очередь будет физически находится вообще на другом оборудовании, поэтому задача особого смысла не имеет.